# jQuery DataTables loaded on onclick with ajax data

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a MVC 5 application utilizing the DataTables jquery library. I've worked with this before, but have always had the table load immediately with the page load.  Currently, I want the page to load and allow the user to add text into a search field, call an AJAX function, and then display the returned data.

The error I'm receiving is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTable' of null' on page load.

Up to this point I've caught a few errors:  Too much data being returned and the wrong order for what's expected back.  These are fixed, but I still get the same error.

I know my AJAX method returns data, and I know my click events are firing.

Here's my client side code, with a quick low-down:
I have a public 'sf' variable to house the datatable instance (.DataTable, not .dataTable). Then I setup the table, with no data field. When the user clicks the search button, the ajax method fires, retrieves data (verified with Fiddler), and within the success method calls the function to add those rows to the to the table.

```
<script>
var sf;

$(document).ready(function () {       
    SetupSalesForceTable();
});

function SetupSalesForceTable() {

    sf = $('#salesForceAccounts').DataTable(
        {
            "destroy": true
            , "processing": true
            , "columns": [
                { "data": "Id" },
                { "data": "AccountNumber" },
                { "data": "Name" }
            ]
        });
}

function LoadSalesForceSearchData() {
    var search = $("#salesForceSearch").val();

    $.ajax(
    {
        "type": "GET"
        , "data": { search: search }
        , "url": "@Url.Action(MyMethod, MyController)"
        , success: function (data) { AddRecordsToTable(data); }
        , error: function () { alert('there was an error! '); }
    });
}

function AddRecordsToTable(data) {

    sf.rows.add(data).draw();
    $("#salesForceAccounts").show();
} </script>
```

As I said, I've worked with DataTables before, but everything was put into the page load, and it works fine.  This time, things are a bit different and I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Am I missing any required parts, or have anything incorrectly configured?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: At this point, I'm not able to display the data, but I've gotten past the errors.  In my html, I didn't have the table correctly created.  It needs to include the thead, tfoot and tbody empty elements.  I had totally forgotten these parts.  So, that's fixed.  Now I need to figure out why the data isn't displaying....

Answer (score 0):

Arrrrg... From another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627133/datatables-ajax-requires-explicit-json-collection-name-for-the-returned-datasour) where I asked/learned about data and dataSrc, I realized that my separate ajax call created a wrapper around my data and was one level deeper than I was assigning.   Ooops.

Here's what my AJAX controller method does (and no, these are not the real method names I use), and I'm returning just a collection of objects.  This works!

```
 [RequireAjax]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoadSalesForceSearchTable(string search)
    {
        var model = this.MyRepo.MyMethod(search);

        var json = this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            

        return json;
    }
```

Below does NOT work with how I have my DataTables object setup.  Originally, I was doing this which was adding a wrapper to the data, called 'data' that I needed with the way I used my previous datatable.  Because my data was one level deeper than I was assigning, I was getting nothing.

```
 [RequireAjax]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoadSalesForceSearchTable(string search)
    {
        var model = this.MyRepo.MyMethod(search);

        var json = this.Json(new { data = model}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return json;
    }
```

Hope this helps you!